# Serialization of derived classes with type T

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class that I need to serialize

```
public class Boat
{
   public string Brand { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

And the following derived classes

```
public class WindBoat : Boat
{
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set }
}

public class SpeedBoat<T> : Boat
{
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    public Engine<T> Engine { get; set; }
}
```

Whan I try to serialize the Boat class, it says I need to add XmlInclude for all possible subclasses, but I can´t add SpeedBoat as I don´t know how many  types I will have in advance, like:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(WindBoat)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SpeedBoat<T>)] <-- Not acceptable
public class Boat
{
   public string Brand { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to allow serializer to go through with the generics ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `typeof(SpeedBoat<>)` ?

Comment: Yes.. Compiles but trigger exception at runtime... It requires a type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may work around this problem by requiring T to be serializable:

```
public class SpeedBoat<T> : Boat where T: IXmlSerializable
{
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
    public Engine<T> Engine { get; set; }
}
```